# ajax call for controller to get number of pages in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the number of pages of an uploaded PDF document. The button click is working, but not going to the controller method.

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" id="fileupload" accept="application/pdf" />
            <button type="button" onclick="pagecount()">Upload</button> 

        @Html.Label("Number Of Pages", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        @ViewBag.pageCount
</div>
```

Here is my ajax script:

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {var frmData = null;
        function pagecount() {
            frmData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("fileupload").files.length;
            var file = document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0];
            frmData.append("fileupload", file);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ProductAPI/PageCount@*@Url.Action("PageCount", "ProductAPI")*@',
                data: frmData,
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PageCount(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var file = Request.Files[0];
    byte[] fileData = new byte[Request.Files[0].ContentLength];
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileData);
    ViewBag.pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the way I did. 
Remove `pageCount()` javascript function from `document.ready()` since you need to call it from outer scope.

add `contentType` and `processData` with false value. Updated funtion

```
 function pagecount() {
        frmData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("fileupload").files.length;
        var file = document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0];
        frmData.append("fileupload", file);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ProductAPI/PageCount',
            dataType: "json",
            data:frmData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#pageCount').html(response);
            },
        });
    }
```

Call this javascript function in button click.

```
 <button type="button" onclick="javascript:pagecount()">Upload</button>
```

In Mvc Action return page count as json object as below

```
  public JsonResult PageCount()
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        byte[] fileData = new byte[Request.Files[0].ContentLength];
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileData);

        return Json(reader.NumberOfPages);
    }
```

Update the view in ajax's success function

```
success: function (response) {
            $('#pageCount').html(response);
        },
```

This works for me :). Thanks

Comment: @moulali Glad if it helped you. :)